# nginx nested location directive inheritance when applies and when does not

Tags: nginx

I know that I have to duplicate the proxy_pass in both locations below, do the proxy_set_headers also have to be duplicated?

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://mywebfeservers;
  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header  X-Client-SSL  YES;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Port  443;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Scheme  https;

  location /aaa {
    proxy_pass http://mywebfeservers;
    client_max_body_size 30M;
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Client-SSL  YES;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Port  443;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Scheme  https;
  }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it absolutely clear documented at the very beginning of the `proxy_set_header` directive [description](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header)? _These directives are inherited from the previous configuration level if and only if there are no `proxy_set_header` directives defined on the current level._

Comment: @IvanShatsky Yes

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically if you remove */aaa* and leave */* you should have the same effect.

If you need use the same configuration of proxy in diferente **locations** you can add the proxy config on a file.

Example:

1. Create file proxy.conf and add this lines

Add

```
proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header  X-Client-SSL  YES;
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Port  443;
proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-Scheme  https;
```

2. Modify your configuration

```
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://mywebfeservers;
        include <your path>/proxy.conf
    }
    
    location /aaa {
       proxy_pass http://mywebfeservers;
       include <your path>/proxy.conf
    }
```

3. Reload your configuration

The main objetive is create a modular configuration (multiple files) that allow you modify single file to modify multiples points of your configuration.

Comment: I've slightly edited my question to add in why I wanted to have the nested location (the nested location adds in a client_max_body_size).  As Ivan pointed out in the comment on the question the documentation, the proxy_set_header in my situation does not need to be duplicated, which avoids the need for the proxy.conf.

Answer (score 0):

Slightly rephrased from the comment by Ivan Shatsky on the question.

It is absolutely clearly documented at the very beginning of the proxy_set_header directive [description](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header).

> These directives are inherited from the previous configuration level
> if and only if there are no proxy_set_header directives defined on the
> current level.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).